# How do you listen to block changes using web3 (1.0.0) and MetaMask ?

Tags: web3js, metamask, events

I need to display a message (in my react app) when the block count reaches a particular number. I tried using web3.eth.subscribe but MetaMask provider does not support that. So is there any other way i can listen to block updates in the blockchain (using ganache for dev).

Comment: An ugly way to do this where I can quickly think of (but not elegant) is to keep calling eth.getBlock() and check if the block has increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One module on npm for this use is eth-block-tracker. It uses polling under the hood, but MetaMask caches redundant requests, so it’s not much worse than MetaMask’s background polling is already.